# Doubt in proof of AM GM inequality by induction Method

Tags: inequality, induction, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image]

---

So, I was going through the *AM-GM inequality* and there is particular part I didn't quite understand. My question is: IF $c_1 <1$ and $c_k+1 > 1$ then how are they considering
$c.c_2.c_3...c_k=1$ ??
I took it as being true assuming that $P(k)$ is true for $n=k$, but just because I'm denoting $c = c_1.c_k+1$ doesn't mean the value of $c_k+1$ is gone, moreover they said that $c_k+1 > 1$, so this could be anything then, $c_k+1$ can be $2, 10 , 100, 500$ so on...

In that case, how will this $c.c_2.c_3\ldots c_n= 1$ hold?? Please help!

Comment: Once again: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It would be nice if you could listen to the community members and learn how to format properly. It's for your own good. You'll get a feedback sooner if the post is _readable_. Try to post images as little as possible. Keep in mind there are other students who would also _profit_ from hearing information you got here. Don't be selfish  and show other users you took their advices into account. You' ve been here long enough to finally follow the rules.  Cheers! 

Comment: I'm trying my best thank you very much for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $c_1\leq1$ and $c_{n+1}\geq1$, we obtain:
$$(c_1-1)\left(c_{n+1}-1\right)\leq0$$ or
$$c_1+c_{n+1}\geq1+c_1c_{n+1}.$$
Thus, by assumption of the induction (if $x_1x_2...x_n=1$ then $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq n$ for positives $x_i$)

we obtain:
$$c_1+c_2+...+c_n+c_{n+1}=c_1+c_{n+1}+c_2+...+c_n\geq$$
$$\geq1+c_1c_{n+1}+c_2+...+c_n\geq1+\left(c_1c_{n+1}\right)c_2...c_n=1+n.$$

Comment: Sir thank you so much for answering, I just have a doubt. No.1) after multiplying (c1-1)(cn+1 - 1)<0 will give us 1+c1.cn+1< c1 + cn+1 right?

Comment: And 2nd Doubt is, I still didn't understand why c.c2.c3....cn= 1? since they already stated that cn+1 is greater than 1 and c denoted the multiplication of c1 and cn+1

Comment: @RiRi I fixed. The assumption of the induction is: for positives $c_i$ such that $c_1c_2...c_n=1$ we have $c_1+c_2+...+c_n\geq n.$ We can rewrite it so: For positives $x_i$ such that $x_1x_2...x_n=1$ we have $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq n.$ We need to prove that if $c_1c_2...c_{n+1}=1$ then $c_1+c_2+...+c_{n+1}\geq n+1$, which I made. See my proof. $x_1=c_1c_{n+1},$ $x_2=c_2$,..., $x_n=c_n$ and we see that $x_1x_2...x_n=c_1c_2...c_{n+1}=1.$